# Can somebody please explain me this? ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2)

Tags: google-bigquery, exploratory-data-analysis

Im not very savvy when it comes tech I verely just started the Google Data Analytics course, but I found my self lost in this query:

ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2)

What exactly I'm asking when writing down this query?
I can't really understand the instructor from the course.

I can run my query with no problem I just can't understand what exactly I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calculates the average trip duration in minutes and rounds it to two decimal places